# Modal Dialog in Shiny: Can adjust width but not height

Tags: css, r, shiny, modal-dialog

In my Shiny app, I have several modal windows from the shinyBS package. I am able to adjust the width of these modal windows like so:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('

                                                  .modal-lg {
                                                  width: 1200px;
                                                  }
                                                  #abs_1 {background-color: white;;}
                                                  #clear{background-color: turquoise3;;}
                                                  #disease{background-color: turquoise3;;}
                                                  #bleach{background-color: turquoise3;;}
                                                  #regionSelect{background-color: turquoise3;;}
                                                  #yearSelect{background-color: turquoise3;;}
                                                  #speciesSelect{background-color: turquoise3;;}
                                                  ')))
```

And altering the number of pixels in the width argument changes the width of the modal windows. However, if I use height instead of width, altering the number of pixels has no effect on the height of the modal windows. Why might this be?

Comment: could you please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You want to modify the height of the modal-body. Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog"),
    tags$head(tags$style(".modal-dialog{ width:1000px}")),
    tags$head(tags$style(".modal-body{ min-height:700px}")),
    bsModal('boxPopUp', 'Test','test')


  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    observeEvent(input$show, {
      toggleModal(session, "boxPopUp", toggle = "toggle")
    })
  }
)
```

---

> EDIT: Answer to Mark's comment below

Yes, you can use the id of the bsModal for that, see below. For example, the first style tag now applies for all div's with class .modal-dialog that are in a div with id boxPopUp1

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    actionButton("show1", "Show modal dialog"),
    actionButton("show2", "Show modal dialog"),
    tags$head(tags$style("#boxPopUp1 .modal-dialog{ width:1000px}")),
    tags$head(tags$style("#boxPopUp1 .modal-body{ min-height:700px}")),
    tags$head(tags$style("#boxPopUp2 .modal-dialog{ width:100px}")),
    tags$head(tags$style("#boxPopUp2 .modal-body{ min-height:100px}")),
    bsModal('boxPopUp1', 'Big','test'),
    bsModal('boxPopUp2', 'Small','test')


  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    observeEvent(input$show1, {
      toggleModal(session, "boxPopUp1", toggle = "toggle")
    })
    observeEvent(input$show2, {
      toggleModal(session, "boxPopUp2", toggle = "toggle")
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Florian, before I spend a lot of time building a demo app and question, would you happen to know how to apply styling tags to individual .modal-dialogs in shiny  if you have for instance 2 of them and you want to style them differently?

Comment: Florian, can i contact you directly through linkedin or such? I have a few follow ups that are more discussion than a comment. (And this SO question isn't mine by the way, but similar to what I was looking for)

Comment: Hi Mark, that's okay, you can find my linkedIn and e-mail on my profile.

Comment: Hello Florian. Even 3 years later this is very useful. How can we do the same thing with the shiny genuine `modalDialog()`? I tried to specify an id without any success.